# Drag and Drop -JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, position

Im creating myself a drag functions just for my personal use so I can drag elements around. I'm having a problem. At the moment trying to make the drag so one you pick up the element you can drag it but once you drop it, it goes back to the original position. This is not working as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/BggPn/3/). When I let go of `#drag2` or `#drag3` then it goes to the position of `#drag1`.

My Function:

```
function drag(el) {
    var position = $(el).position();
    var ptop = position.top;
    var pleft = position.left;
    var down = false;
    $(el).mousedown(function(event) {
        down = true;
        $(this).css({
            cursor: 'crosshair',
        });
        $(this).mousemove(function(event) {
            if (down == true) {
                $(this).css({
                    cursor: 'crosshair',
                });
                var w = $(this).width();
                var h = $(this).height();
                var left3 = (w / 2) + 7;
                var top3 = (h / 2) + 7;
                $(this).css({
                    cursor: 'crosshair',
                    left: (event.clientX) + (3 * 3) - left3,
                    top: (event.clientY) + (3 * 3) - top3
                });
            }
        }).mouseup(function() {
            down = false;
            $(this).css({
                cursor: 'default',
            });
            $(this).animate({
                top: ptop,
                left: pleft
            }, 300);
        });
    });
}
```

I have to get the old position:

```
        var position = $(el).position();
        var ptop = position.top;
        var pleft = position.left;
```

So should it not get the position of all of them and bring them self back to where they were? Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT: I DO *NOT* WANT TO USE ANY PLUGIN OR JQUERY UI, THANKS ANYWAYS**

Comment: use jQuery with [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com)
there you will have [drag and drop](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) as function

Comment: Well, I like to make my own things. I get it would be easier though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very simple

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BggPn/4/

you define 1 var for left and 1 for top. All 3 the elements use the same variables. If you loop through the elements then you make a new scope where each element has it's own vars.

Working code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    drag('#drag, #drag2, #drag3')
});

function drag(el) {
    $(el).each(function(){
        var position = $(this).position();
        var ptop = position.top;
        var pleft = position.left;
        var down = false;
        $(this).mousedown(function(event) {
            down = true;
            $(this).css({
                cursor: 'crosshair',
            });
            $(this).mousemove(function(event) {
                if (down == true) {
                    $(this).css({
                        cursor: 'crosshair',
                    });
                    var w = $(this).width();
                    var h = $(this).height();
                    var left3 = (w / 2) + 7;
                    var top3 = (h / 2) + 7;
                    $(this).css({
                        cursor: 'crosshair',
                        left: (event.clientX) + (3 * 3) - left3,
                        top: (event.clientY) + (3 * 3) - top3
                    });
                }
            }).mouseup(function() {
                down = false;
                $(this).css({
                    cursor: 'default',
                });
                $(this).animate({
                    top: ptop,
                    left: pleft
                }, 300);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

**Make it a plugin:**

```
$.fn.drag = function drag(){
    return this.each(function(){
        var position = $(this).position();
        var ptop = position.top;
        var pleft = position.left;
        var down = false;
        $(this).mousedown(function(event) {
            down = true;
            $(this).css({
                cursor: 'crosshair',
            });
            $(this).mousemove(function(event) {
                if (down == true) {
                    $(this).css({
                        cursor: 'crosshair',
                    });
                    var w = $(this).width();
                    var h = $(this).height();
                    var left3 = (w / 2) + 7;
                    var top3 = (h / 2) + 7;
                    $(this).css({
                        cursor: 'crosshair',
                        left: (event.clientX) + (3 * 3) - left3,
                        top: (event.clientY) + (3 * 3) - top3
                    });
                }
            }).mouseup(function() {
                down = false;
                $(this).css({
                    cursor: 'default',
                });
                $(this).animate({
                    top: ptop,
                    left: pleft
                }, 300);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Now you can call it by:

```
$("#drag1, #drag2").drag();
```

Answer (score 0):

get the current position of div after drag and set via this

```
.mouseup(function() {
            var position = $(this).position();
            down = false;
            $(this).css({
                cursor: 'default',
            });
            $(this).animate({
                top: position.top,
                left: position.left
            }, 300);
```

[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/BggPn/6/)

---

why don't you use drag and drop plugin. see this article

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/05/implement-drag-and-drop-example-jquery-javascript-html.html

or this one

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dragndrop

Comment: is this an answer? you say he should do something what might be better for him but you don't answer his question

Comment: Well, I like to make my own things. I get it would be easier though. I just hit some bumps on the way of developing new things. Thanks though.

Comment: and drag and drop plugin is no plugin it is an extension for jQuery  like jQuery template but in this case jQuery UI
jQuery image viewer would be a plugin

Answer (score 0):

2 thoughts: 
1.) Why don't you use jQuery UI (draggable)?

2.) The idea of giving a selector in stead of an element is wrong, a selector can lead to multiple elements, and that's the first reason why it's failing. If you start with

```
function drag(selector) {
   $(selector).each(function() {
      var el = $(this);
      //rest of code
   }
}
```

it would be better. But I think you'll run into a few other problems eventually

Answer (score 0):

The problem is whenever you're sending in the list of selectors `'#drag, #drag2. #drag3'` and your position variable only cares about the first one (try changing the order and you'll see they snap to the first in the list). If you want to go about it this way then you'll want to perform an `each` iteration over them to get the right values.